# Скрыть таб при повторном клике

Tags: javascript

Решил покопаться с JS без использования jQuery. Простая задачка при наличии упомянутой библиотеки, но, все же.

Итак. Есть некий набор элементов с заголовком и содержимым. Я делаю список, основываясь на содержимом заголовка и вытаскивая ID из каждого блока. После формирования списка, скрываю все блоки и делаю простые табы. То есть, при нажатии на пункт списка, идет сравнение ID и открывается нужный блок.

Теперь вопросы:

1. Как сделать так, чтоб при повторном нажатии на пункт списка, блок скрывался? Попытки записать эту строчку `document.getElementById(filterName).style.display = 'block';` с условием результата не дают, почему-то, на повторное нажатие она не реагирует.
2. Просто окинуть проф.взглядом, можно ли что-то записать более коротко и корректно, если что-то колхозно сделано.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-area > .element'),
  b = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-area > .element > h2'),
  c = '',
  d = document.getElementsByClassName('filter_list'),
  i;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  c += '<div class="fl-item" onclick="openFilter(event, \'' + a[i].id + '\')">' + b[i].innerHTML + '</div>';
  a[i].style.display = 'none';
}
window.filter_list.innerHTML = c;

function openFilter(evt, filterName) {
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    d[i].className = d[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  document.getElementById(filterName).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_list" class="filter_list"></div>
<div class="filter-area">
  <div class="element" id="e1"><h2>Title 1</h2><p>Dummy</p></div>
  <div class="element" id="e2"><h2>Title 2</h2><p>Text</p></div>
  <div class="element" id="e3"><h2>Title 3</h2><p>Here</p></div>
</div>
```

Спасибо за любые мысли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-area > .element'),
  b = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-area > .element > h2'),
  c = '',
  d = document.getElementsByClassName('filter_list'),
  i;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  c += '<div class="fl-item" onclick="openFilter(event, \'' + a[i].id + '\')">' + b[i].innerHTML + '</div>';
  a[i].style.display = 'none';
}
window.filter_list.innerHTML = c;

function openFilter(evt, filterName) {
  var wasVisible = document.getElementById(filterName).style.display != 'none';
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    d[i].className = d[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  document.getElementById(filterName).style.display = wasVisible? 'none' : 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}
```

```html
<div id="filter_list" class="filter_list"></div>
<div class="filter-area">
  <div class="element" id="e1">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>Dummy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element" id="e2">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element" id="e3">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```